# Rotating a Line by an Angle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

I have a line drawn between 2 points A(100, 100) and B(100, 200) which I would like to rotate about point A by x degrees. Apparently the code only works for 45 degrees. I tried 90 degrees and it looks way wrong. I hope someone will be able to point out what's wrong.

```
float newX = 100.0f;
float newY = 100.0f;
float newX1 = 100.0f;
float newY1 = 200.0f;
float degree = 90.0;
float x, y;
x = newX1;
y = newY1;
x -= newX;
y -= newY;
newX1 = (x * cos(degree)) - (y * sin(degree));
newY1 = (x * sin(degree)) + (y * cos(degree));
newX1 += newX;
newY1 += newY;
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, newX, newY);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, newX1, newY1);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

Comment: For starters - `sin()` and `cos()` take their angles in radians, so 90 degrees is π/2 and 45 degrees is π/4.